# Destructuring multilevel and and assigning default value to a first level object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to destructure the a response from the API. response looks something like below.
Only `a` and `b` will be used in the program.

```
response = {
   data: {
       someData: {
    a:1,
    b:2
    }

   }
}
```

destructured
`const {data: { someData: { a,b } } } = response`

Now if data doesn't exist in the response, there are chances that app might break. I want set default value to `data` and `someData`. Is there a way to set the default value?

**Tried** : but throwing lint error as unexpected token

`const {data= {}: { someData = {}: { a,b } } } = response`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the default values as shown below:

```
const {data: { someData: { a, b } = {} } = {} } = response;
```

[This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values) on MDN docs shows that the default value should be at the end, not immediately after the property name.

If the unpacked property is `undefined`, then the default value will be used  as a target for the nested destructuring.

**Example:**

```js
const response = {
  data: {}
};

const {data: { someData: { a, b } = {} } = {} } = response;

console.log(a, b);
```

Another option is to use optional chaining which, in my opinion, is a better approach here for code readability:

```
response?.data?.someData?.a
```

Answer (score 4):

The default value goes at the end, not immediately after the variable.

And it needs to have the `someData:` nested object to provide the default there.

```js
const response = {};

const {data: {someData: { a,b } } = {someData: {a:0, b:0}} } = response;

console.log(a, b);
```